# Setting Spannable.Factory for all TextViews within a Theme

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow set `TextView`s with a given Theme to have a `Spannable.Factory`-instance without having to manually declare:

- a new type of `TextView` (one which extends `TextView` and in the constructor somewhere overriding the factory)
- or set it on every instance of `TextView` after inflating it.

Ideally it would be nice to have something like

```
<TextView
 android:spannableFactory="com.mypackage.Class"
/>
```

Worst case is that it makes a new instance of the class each time, but even that is more desirable than having to explicitly deal with setting the factory every time.

Comment: Since there is no XML-attribute for this, i think you first approach is the best suited one.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am thinking too :( I totally would love this feature. It would allow you to fix all the weird bugs with text rendering and interaction without having to put all if/else like logic all over the place for different API levels.